# Link behaviour in Datatables row not behaving the same as link outside of datatables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a row in my datatables that shows a url with the rows Id attached to it. When you click that link, it is supposed to open up a modal window and load the url. However, for some reason it just redirects to a new page and shows the form that was supposed to be in the modal window.

When I access this same link that is located outside the datatables, the modal window opens and loads the url properly.

The attribute rel = "modal:open"  is the one that opens the modal window. This is the jquery modal library i'm using https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal

I'm not too sure why the same links are having different behaviours.

Here is my code

Link that works as per normal:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "RoleDetails", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), null, new { @class = "btn btn-default pull-right", @rel = "modal:open" })
```

Link in datatables that redirects to another page:

```
"columns": [
        {
            "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                 var url = "@Url.Action("RoleDetails", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())" + data.Id;
                 return "<a href=" + url + " rel=\"model:open\">" + data.Name + "</i></a>"
            }, "name": "Name" 
        },
    ],
```

Or is there a way to use @Html.ActionLink on the datatables url? I'm not sure whats missing.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I should have done this to my rel attribute

```
rel='modal:open'
```

I managed to get it working like this.